# apex:commandButton redirect with rerender tag

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a commandButton that call two actionfunctions the two actionfunctions call to methods that return a String, but one of the methods some time return null, and when the method return null the visualforce page is reloaded , I try putting a rerender attribute but is not working the visualforce page reload everything when the method return null, the button is "Exportar" this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loading(val) {
        //document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm1.theBlock.theSection.theSectionItemTipo.typeCard}').value;
        if (val) {
            document.getElementById('contentLoading').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('contentLoaded').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('contentLoading').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('contentLoaded').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
<apex:form id="theForm1">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Reporte Donaciones Recurrentes" id="theBlock">
        <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />

        <apex:actionFunction name="showbn" action="{!chooseCardType}" reRender="theSection,theSectionItemBanco,theSectionItemBlank" status="loading">
            <apex:param name="mediodePago" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:actionFunction name="showpn" action="{!showPreNotificacion}" reRender="theSection,theSectionItemBlank" status="loading">
            <apex:param name="nombreBanco" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <apex:actionFunction name="generate" action="{!generateURL}" reRender="{!If(cards=='Visa','errors,buttons','')}" status="{!If(cards=='Visa','loading','')}"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="disable" action="{!runUpdate}" reRender="errors,buttons" status="loading"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="redirectPre" action="{!redirectPreURL}"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="enable" action="{!enableExport}" reRender="buttons" status="loading"/>

        <apex:actionStatus id="loading" onstart="loading(true)" onstop="loading(false)" />

        <apex:pageblockSection id="theSection" title="Filtros de búsqueda">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemMedio" rendered="{!showFinancia}">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Medio de Pago" for="medioCard" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Donation.Medio_de_Pago__c}" id="medioCard" onchange="showbn(this.value);"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemTipo" rendered="{!showFinancia}">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Tipo de Tarjeta" for="typeCard" />
                <apex:selectList id="typeCard" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!card}" disabled="{!!cardt}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!cards}" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemBanco" rendered="{!bank}">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Entidad de Cobro" for="entidadCobro" />
                <apex:selectList id="cobrador" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!cobra}" onchange="showpn(this.value);">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!cobradores}" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemBlank" rendered="{!bank}">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Pre Notificación" for="preNotificacion" rendered="{!preNotificacion}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Donation.Pre_Notificado__c}" id="preNotificado" rendered="{!preNotificacion}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemDesde">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Fecha Desde" for="fromDate" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Donation.npe03__Date_Established__c}" id="fromDate" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemHasta">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Fecha Hasta" for="toDate" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!DonationHasta.npe03__Date_Established__c}" id="toDate" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemSemana">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Semana de Cobro" for="weekPay" />
                <apex:selectList id="weekPay" multiselect="true" size="5" value="{!semana}" style="width:50px;">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!semanas}" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemEstado">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Estado" for="status" />
                <!--  <apex:inputField value="{!npe03__Recurring_Donation__c.npe03__Open_Ended_Status__c}" id="status"/>  -->
                <apex:selectList id="status" multiselect="true" size="3" value="{!estado}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!estados}" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <!--  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSectionItemInStop" >
                <apex:outputLabel value="En pausa" for="inStop"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!npe03__Recurring_Donation__c.En_Pausa__c}" id="inStop"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> -->
        </apex:pageblockSection>
        <div id="contentLoaded">
            <apex:pageblockSection id="buttons">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Buscar" action="{!runSearch}" reRender="grilla,debug,errors,buttons" status="loading"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Pre Visualizar" onclick="redirectPre();" oncomplete="enable();" disabled="{!!exportedPre}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Exportar" onclick="generate();" oncomplete="disable();" disabled="{!!exported}" />                     
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </div>
        <div id="contentLoading" style="display: none;">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <img src="/img/loading.gif" alt="Procesando..." />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <apex:pageblockSection id="grilla" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!resultado}" var="c">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Id Donación" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Id" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Id}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="PSN" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="PSN__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.PSN__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Nombre Cuenta" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="AccountId" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Nombre_Cuenta__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Nombre" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Nombre__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Nombre__c}" />
                </apex:column>                  
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Apellido" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Apellidos__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Apellidos__c}" />
                </apex:column>                  
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="DNI" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="N_mero_de_Documento__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.N_mero_de_Documento__c}" rendered="{!c.N_mero_de_Documento__c!=null}"/>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Account.N_Fiscal__c}" rendered="{!c.N_mero_de_Documento__c==null}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Monto" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Amount" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Amount}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Tipo Tarjeta" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Tipo_de_Tarjeta__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Tipo_de_Tarjeta__c}" />
                </apex:column>                  
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Número Tarjeta" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Numero_de_Tarjeta__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Numero_de_Tarjeta__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Fecha Vencimiento" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Fecha_de_Vencimiento__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Fecha_de_Vencimiento__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Número Cuenta" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Numero_de_Tarjeta__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Numero_de_Cuenta__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Frecuencia" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="grilla,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Frecuencia__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!c.Frecuencia__c}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:pageMessages />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: If the card is NOT visa "it should reload"

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another actionfuction that rerender another tags and I created a javascript function that is called from the commandbutton this function obtain the credit card and call to the corresponding actionfunction.

Comment: Is this post meant to be an answer? Or did you intend to edit your question? It's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution:

**Command button** 
Added `return` to prevent commandbutton default action.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
   <apex:commandButton value="Pre Visualizar" onclick="redirectPre(); return false;" oncomplete="enable();" disabled="{!!exportedPre}" />
   <apex:commandButton value="Exportar" onclick="generate(); return false;" oncomplete="disable();" disabled="{!!exported}" />                     
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

**Action function:** 
 Added `fakeID` so page don't reload.
**Updated:**

```
<apex:actionFunction name="generate" rendered="{!cards=='Visa'}" action="{!generateURL}" reRender="errors,buttons" status="loading"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="generate" rendered="{!cards!='Visa'}" action="{!generateURL}" reRender="fakeID" status=""/>
```

Comment: I tried it, but this not working, I think the condicional isn't working because instead of fakeID I put erros,buttons, and doesn't redirect, but can't see the error in the conditional, can you?

Comment: try changing actionfunctin to `<apex:actionFunction name="generate" action="{!generateURL}" reRender="errors,buttons" status="{!If(cards=='Visa','loading','')}"/> ` @AngelloCamacho

Comment: ok but only need to rerender when the cards equals to Visa

Comment: @AngelloCamacho My doubt is there is issue with `IF`. If this works we can workaround the solution

Comment: I changed it and doesn't redirect but the status is not showing.

Comment: You are using it in wrong way. It won't support condition in it. You will have to specify ID.

Comment: @AngelloCamacho updated the answer